# FTP Upload Problem - 0 bytes transfered

Tags: apache, ftp

In one of our project we are using Apache's FTP client APIs.
 I have to upload xml file to a FTP server, where a process will keep polling that server directory. So using the upload API, I am uploading the xml file with .TRANSFER extension, and after successfully uploading full file, the file will be renamed to .xml file.

The weird problem I am facing was that, sometimes the file size of the file is 0 bytes. but the same file sometimes fully gets uploaded. When I looked at log file, the transfered bytes are 0 kb only. So I am not sure what could be the problem.

I am using linux server and Apache's commons's FTP client APIs.

Any debugging tips and tricks will be helpful.

Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 5):

I too ran into this a while back.

I noticed that if the file was bigger than a certain size (it was 174 bytes or so for me), it did get transferred correctly. Smaller files ended up being created as zero byte files.

I believe it is a bug in the Apache commons ftp code. I fixed it by getting the source and did a quick fix and the resulting jar that I built worked for us.

If I remember the fix right, I disabled Nagle's algorithm with socket.setTcpNoDelay(false) on the socket that was being used for the transfer in the commons ftp code.

Answer (score 2):

If it happens sometimes, it smells like a firewall configuration on one of the ends. Hard to diagnose, but start (if you can) try switching between active/passive.

Look here for a better reference: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Answer (score 2):

Another possible firewall config issue:  If you are ftp'ing from a linux/unix box with iptables configured, make sure that you have the tables configured to allow ftp "connection tracking".

In the course of the ftp transaction, your client machine establishes the ftp connection, then issues the ftp STOR command to upload the file. The initial part of the transaction takes place on the standard ftp sockets (20,21), then switches to a random high-numbered port selected by the ftp server if in ACTIVE mode, or by the client if in PASSIVE (PASV) mode.  If you are in ACTIVE mode iptables may not allow the server to communicate with your client machine on this randomly selected port, you will get a zero-byte file with the correct name and no other data.

You can fix this by switching the transaction to PASSIVE mode from the client side, or by setting iptables on the client machine to do "connection tracking":

http://www.linuxchix.org/content/courses/security/connection_tracking

Comment: Turning the Passive mode on solved my problem , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your disk capacity. I faced to this kind of situation when I was working on Raspberry Pi project. I had to work with large files downloads and it caused to fill-up RPi's SD card very quickly. After reaching some extent FTP uploads 0 bytes files. 
Not only for small storage, this can be happened anywhere. For example, your server can create gigabytes of error log files. After sometime your server space will be filled by those log files. Again same thing happens on FTP uploads. Check that out too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try running WireShark and see what is going across the wire?  That might give you a clue as to where the problem lies.

http://www.wireshark.org/